# Change "List of symbols" to "List of Symbols"

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I'd just like to change "List of symbols" to "List of Symbols" in my thesis. How to do this?

[image]

I'm using these lines of code:

```
  \input{inc/nomenclature}
  \markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
  \printnomenclature
  \cleardoublepage
```

Comment: Can you make a small compilable document that reproduces your problem? As you have also been asked to do for your previous questions ....

Answer (score 2):

The setting `\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}` should go *before* `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I just changed the order to:

```
\input{inc/nomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}
\printnomenclature
\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: Please always elaborate on why an answer achieves the effect. In this case it would probably help to include the other relevant lines (e.g. `\printnomenclature`).